# Xamarin Forms DisplayAlert(): Why are there different number of arguments in WinPhone and Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to use `DisplayAlert` in my ContentPage to show a simple message to be confirmed by clicking the "OK" button, so my third argument is "OK". This means: I don't need the fourth argument for the second button. Now I found a discrepancy between Windows Phone and Android:

- Using null with Android throws an exception wheras using only three
  arguments works.
- Using three arguments with WinPhone gives the
  compile time error "No overload for method 'DisplayAlert' takes 3
  arguments".

I wonder: Do I have to write a DependencyService only to display an alert with just one button?

WinPhone runtime version: v4.0.30319
Android support version: v5

---

Update to Dylan's comment:

```
async void OnMyEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Message 1", "Hello Android!", "OK"); // <- works on Android but doesn't compile on WinPhone
    await DisplayAlert("Message 2", "Hello WinPhone!", "OK", null); // <- works on WinPhone but throws a null pointer exception on Android
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code that is calling DisplayAlert? Are you using it from a PCL or SAP? I'm not sure how you could be getting different compilation results on Android and Windows Phone if you're using one of those.

Comment: @Dylan: Done. I'm using a shared project. Not sure how it would behave in a PCL.

Answer (score 6):

You can have the OK button as the cancel button, like this:

```
var result = await DisplayAlert("Message", "Hello there!", null, "OK");
```

This will show an alert box with only an OK button. Then check if `result` is `false`. If it is, that means the "OK" button was clicked.

E.g.

```
var result = await DisplayAlert("Message", "Hello there!", null, "OK");
if (!result) //result is false
    //Do something
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my workaround for now:

```
#if __ANDROID__
            await DisplayAlert("Message 1", "Hello Android!", "OK");
#else
            await DisplayAlert("Message 2", "Hello WinPhone!", "OK", null);
#endif
```

Maybe there is a better one...